# Database Migrations and Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I haven't deployed a production application yet but I plan on doing so soon. When I create migrations in a development environment will those changes reflect my final database structure when I deploy?

In other words, do migrations occur on the production side as well?

Comment: Migrations need to occur on the production side, otherwise your database will just have the old table structure. In heroku you push to heroku and then also run something like `heroku run bundle exec rails c`. With engineyard, you can pass an argument to deploy `ey deploy --migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, make sure how you are deploying your application ? Rails use tools or gem called `capistrano` to deploy the application. But there other cloud platform service that provide facility to deploy the application like heroku.

If you are deploying with capistrano, to migrate database you can add  `after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"` command to your config file. Use [this](http://capistranorb.com/) as reference.

If you are deploying it in heroku, to migrate you can run `heroku run rake db:migrate` command. Follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3) for complete reference.

There several other cloud platform service to deploy. Check out there documentation and deploy it.

Comment: Amritdeep's answer helped me the most but all answers were great. I plan on deploying to a local server to be used in our corporate intranet. I imagine I would use a tool like capistrano to do this. Is that correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The normal `cap deploy` does not migrate the database, it only updates the code, compiles assets etc. If you also want to run your migrations, use `cap deploy:migrations`, or go with what @Vimsha suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your deploy script.

If you are using `capistrano`, you can add this line to your `deploy` namespace to make migration part of the deploy

```
  after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"
```